# RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension when trying running the AWQ

Tags: runtime-error, ninja

I was configuring the env of this github post:https://github.com/mit-han-lab/llm-awq
Everything ran smoothly until installing the python setup file in step 3:

`python setup.py install`

And it returned the following errors:

ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jc/anaconda3/envs/awq/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 2100, in _run_ninja_build
subprocess.run(
File "/home/jc/anaconda3/envs/awq/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
raise RuntimeError(message) from e
```

RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension